# Match if word does not appear before another word in regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that matches if a keyword does not appear somewhere in a string before a stopword.

Example:

This should not match anything:

> aaa: OK
>
> bbb: Failed
>
> ccc: OK
>
> stopword
>
> Random Text OK Failed Random Text

This should match:

> aaa: OK
>
> bbb: OK
>
> ccc: OK
>
> stopword
>
> Random Text OK Failed Random Text

I guess I should use a negative check `^(?!.*Failed)` but how do I stop checking at [stopword]?

I'm trying to do this with pythons regex engine if that matters.

Edit: Sorry for being unclear. Yes, it's "Failed" I want to not match against and unfortunately I need a "regex"-solution ie `re.search(regex, string)` since I does not have any access to the code outside of the input variables regex and string.

If I could do it directly in Python I would have avoided regex to start with. ;)

Comment: Your question is unclear. could you add some more explanation?

Comment: Yes, I agree with @AvinashRaj I read your question 3 times now and I still don't get exactly what you mean.

Comment: No idea what is wanted with this question

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want to make sure the string `'Failed'` does not appear anywhere before the string `'stopword'`. Assuming that's the case, it's easiest to just look for a `Failed` appearing before a `stopword` and then invert your result. Assuming `text` is your input:

```
not re.match(r'.*?Failed.*?stopword', text, re.DOTALL)
```

Of course, this is much easier with straight python:

```
'Failed' not in text.split('stopword')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you're trying to achieve, you're not explaining it very well.

If you want to check for the presence of "Failed" in a string but not after a particular substring, then split the string on it and only look in the first part.

```
>>> sample1 = """
... aaa: OK
... bbb: Failed
... ccc: OK
... stopword
... Random Text OK Failed Random Text
... """
>>> sample2 = """
... aaa: OK
... bbb: OK
... ccc: OK
... stopword
... Random Text OK Failed Random Text
... """
>>>
>>> print "Failed in sample1:", 'Failed' in sample1.partition('stopword')[0]
Failed in sample1: True
>>> print "Failed in sample2:", 'Failed' in sample2.partition('stopword')[0]
Failed in sample2: False
>>>
```